# Splitting up string in C and making conversions from standard input

Tags: c, string, input

Say I have a command coming from standard input in the format "< command > < id > < value>" (so 3 separate sections each separated by one space). How can I split this up such that command will be a string, id is an integer and value is stored in an integer? I was thinking of reading as a string first and then using the atoi function for id and value but that seems inefficient. Could anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

This might help :

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    char str[50],com[50],val[50],id[50];
    int value,idd,i=0,j=0;
    printf("Enter String :");
    scanf("%[^\n]%*c", str);

    while(str[i]!=' ')
    {
        com[i]=str[i];
        i++;
    }
    com[i]='\0';
    i++;

    while(str[i]!=' ')
    {
        id[j]=str[i];
        i++;
        j++;
    }
    id[j]='\0';
    i++;
    j=0;

    while(str[i]!='\0')
    {
        val[j]=str[i];
        i++;
        j++;
    }
    val[j]='\0';

    value=atoi(val);
    idd=atoi(id);

    printf("%s %d %d",com,idd,value);

}
```